# how to fix this dictionaryValue

Tags: swift, alamofire, swifty-json

```
Alamofire.request(.GET,  "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json", parameters:["placeid": x , "key":"AIzaSyAasdaXW-j8DIgGjY58_HdrasdaqqA"])
                .responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
                    //debugPrint(responseData)


                    switch responseData.result{

                    case .Success(let req):
                        let response = JSON(req)

                        let items = response["result"]["geometry"]["location"].dictionaryValue

                        let lat: Double = Double(items["lat"]!.doubleValue)
                        let lng: Double = Double(items["lng"]!.doubleValue)

                        print(lat,lng)



                        for item in items{


                        self.mapResult.append(mapModel(json:item)) // *THIS ERROR AS CANNOT CONVERT VALUE of TYPE '(STRING:JSON)' to EXPECTED ARGUMENT TYPE 'JSON'

                        }

                    case .Failure(let err):
                      print("Request failed with error: \(err)")
                    }
            }
```

Comment: what should i do the the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `items` is a dictionary, then you have to iterate it like this:

```
for (key, value) in items {
}
```

so that you can pass value into that function instead of passing a dictionary element into it. The error you are seeing is telling you you are pass a dictionary argument (String:JSON) while it expects a JSON argument.

Comment: sir can you give me some example??

Comment: i have struct model to call in swift

Comment: i try to do that but theres error .
  the error is 
'JSON' is not convertible to ([JSON],[JSON])